# The symbol of changed column still present after saving Interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I'm working with APEX oracle 23.1
I have an editable (add/delete) interactive grid. After adding new row, the red rectangle in the upper corner of header is displayed. Then when I click save button in toolbar, that red rectangle still present and columns are now in grey (which means not editable). (as the following first image)
Is there any method that those red rectangle will be hidden after saving, and all columns are in white (as in the second image) without refresh the whole page (since I have several IG in the same page).

Thanks in advance for any help.

- observed

[image]

- expected

[image]

Comment: Those red rectangles indicate the column value is required.
A changed column value is indicated by a blue rectangle in the cell itself.

Answer (score 0):

Select the columns that red color corner are showing, then set `Value Required` to `No` in Validation setting.
(If you don't really need these columns data to be entered mandatory)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Those columns must be not null in database.